# DiskSpaceRequirement Dialog doesn't calculate the space required for .net framework installation?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

My basic msi project doesn't calculate the space required for .net framework installation...

How can i do this in installshield in basic msi project...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [ReserveCost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table.

[image]

Also read this [thread](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=181476) for gotchas associated with destination directories for reserve cost.

Comment: How to create entry in ReserveCost table for featured prerequisites?

Comment: Your Feature Prereq is associated to a feature.  Create a component and associate it to that feature then drill down to Advanced Settings | Other Data and click on the ReseveCost link.  This will take you to the ReserveCost table in the Direct Editor.   Create a new row and fill out all the information as described in the ReserveCost MSDN topic I linked you to.